# Upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 Preview

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04

Is there any way to upgrade my distro from 14.04 to the development version of 16.04.

Using

```
update-manager -d
```

tells me about 14.10, which is weird since this version is not suppported anymore.

Comment: Run `do-release-upgrade`. I upgraded this way with no problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `do-release-upgrade -d` (the -d flag to upgrade to a development version)

more info at [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. It tries to retrieve utopic.tar.gz.

Comment: Open `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and make sure that the release upgrader is set to LTS using `Prompt=lts`

Comment: Fantastic it worked!